# Significance of Facebook Location id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Making an api call requesting friends name, id and location,

```
FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'name,id,location'}, function(response) {
//...
});
```

returns two parameters for location (id and name).  The "name" parameter specifies friends location but what is the significance of the "id" parameter?

If that parameter is pretty important, how can it be of use to facebook app developers?

I have been searching for an answer for this question for a quiet sometime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `what is the significance of the "id" parameter` are you kidding? If not, you gotta read the documentation first.

Comment: I tried looking, couldn't find a proper explanation. Providing a link would be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This it the object id in the open graph. You can query information about this location from the grah. For example this is my hometown: http://graph.facebook.com/106013482772674

Every object on the graph is represented by an id. Locations, being objects themselves have it as well.

Comment: Does this id vary depending upon location or user. i.e, if two of my friends are in the same location, will they have the same location id?

Comment: yes. it's the same as to ask me if you and your friend have a common friend if that is the same guy.

Comment: Thanks, its pretty clear now, so does that mean facebook has a location id for each lat/lng or over a specific area of given radius?

Comment: Definitely not. I've never searched how locations are added to the graph but most points of interest are there.

Comment: I tried searching for that, did not come across anything that could help. Anyways, I get a location id for each and every friend who has specified a location in facebook, is there any way that id could help filter friends near you or based on a specific location?

Comment: I think you should start another topic for further questions. Things are getting quite out of the scope of the current question.

Comment: Please accept this answer and previous if people helped you. Otherwise soon people will stop answering to your questions.